# Is it possible in json schema to define a constraint between two properties

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have two fields in my schema - one is a required property called "name" and the other is optional (used to define a sorting property) called "nameSort" and I want to express

If the "nameSort" field is defined, the "name" field should also be defined as the same value.

Is it possible to express such an "inter-element" constraint with JSON schema? My cursory read of JSON Schema here http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html says no.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can express one property must be *defined* when another is present, e.g.:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "dependencies": {
        "nameSort": ["name"]
    }
}
```

However, you cannot specify that two properties must have equal values.

Also, why do you have a separate property at all, if it's always going to be equal?  And if it's always equal, could you just have a boolean flag to reduce redundancy?

Comment: Thanks for that tip - that will help! Yes this is legacy code and some poor design decisions were made that are already in production with customers :-(

Comment: What is that what is that? Did you forget that you could just `"dependencies": { "p1": "p2" }`? :p @kellyfj this will work as to _require_ the property; however, if you want both to have the same VALUE, you'll have to have a custom keyword if you can afford it. Now, it depends on the validation library you use...

Comment: Oops - yeah, I drafted more complicated constraints then forgot about it!  Fixed - thanks. :)

Comment: A use case for comparing equality of values would be a `password` and `password-repeat` pair.  So, is that possible?

Comment: I see that this proposal https://github.com/json-schema/json-schema/wiki/$data-(v5-proposal) can provide the means for this.  This project supports it https://github.com/acornejo/jjv

Answer (score 10):

Old question, but this can now be done with json schema v5/v6 using a combination of the `constant` and `$data` (JSON pointer or relative JSON pointer) keywords.

Example:

```
"properties": {
    "password": { "type": "string" },
    "password_confirmation": { "const": { "$data": "1/password" } }
}
```

Where `"1/password"` is a relative JSON pointer saying "go up one level, then look up the key password".

Comment: JSON schema does _not_ support `$data` as of draft 07, although validators like AJV does. See https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/51 for details.

Comment: As above, this is a non standard keyword and will NOT be interoperable between implementations.