# How can I compare two values using jsonschema?

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have two parameters, say `number_1` and `number_2`. The value of `number_2` should be greater than the value of `number_1`. How can this be done in jsonschema?

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done with plain jsonschema. There is no `greater than` or similar in the [draft](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html). Other constraints could be possible once you can have [access to another value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27907722/is-it-possible-in-json-schema-to-define-a-constraint-between-two-properties).